# How to pass a variable having a dollar sign to another variable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am using an On-Prem Server to run VSTS Build/Releases.
Currently, I am trying to pass a variable from VSTS: `$(password)` to my script.
Suppose the value of this variable `$(password)` is  'stringwith$sign'`

This variable `$(password)` needs to be injected into a string in my script:

```
$string = "I need to inject my password string from VSTS here "$(password)""
```

The String should look like this:

```
$string = I need to inject my password string from VSTS here "stringwith$sign"
```

How do I achieve this? The build/release will fail if I simply add it as $(password) since it thinks `$sign` in `"stringwith$sign"` is a variable. I cannot even use `''` quotes since my variable `$(password)` needs to be inserted in `$string`.

Comment: Can you please provide a small script that illustrates the problem you're having? I'm having difficulty understanding what you're asking.

Comment: An eleborate example:
consider a VSTS variable $(password).
Suppose $password is 'foo$pass'
A custom powershell task in VSTS has the following string:
$getUserPassword = "the password is $(password)".
On running a build/release, this will fail when VSTS inserts $(password) into the $getUserPassword string as PowerShell will think that $pass in 'foo$pass' is a variable too.
Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing any sample code, it's a bit hard to tell how your script works.

But basically, if you are setting a string literal that contains special characters, you can stop them from being parsed by using single quotes instead of double-quotes. For example, if you execute

```
$password = "stringwith$sign"
$password
```

Then the value of password is `stringwith`.

This is because powershell has parsed the string and treated $sign as being the name of a variable and has attempted to insert the value of $sign. But as $sign hasn't been declared, the default value of empty string is used.

However, if you used single quotes, i.e.

```
$password = 'stringwith$sign'
$password
```

Then the value of password is `stringwith$sign`.

Subsequently, setting

```
$string = "I need to inject my password string from VSTS here ""$password"""
```

gives $string the value of

`I need to inject my password string from VSTS here "stringwith$sign"`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the format **`${env:password}`** instead of `$(password)` to get the variable password's value.

Such as if you add a PowerShell task with below script:

```
$string="I need to inject my password string from VSTS here ${env:test}" 
echo $string
```

Then it will show `I need to inject my password string from VSTS here stringwith$sign` in the build log.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use format operator:

```
$myVar = 'okay$dollar'
'My string with my var {0} inside' -f $myVar
```

or `Get-Variable`:

```
$myVar = 'okay$dollar'
"My string with my var $(Get-Variable myvar | select -expandproperty value) inside"
```